# Automator action shell script to tar multiple files/folders (containing spaces)

Tags: bash, shell, tar, automator

I am trying to create an shell script (for use in an Automator action) that creates a `.tar` archive of multiple files, some of which *contain spaces as part of the path or filename*. I have read through many questions on SO concerning tar creation, but couldn't piece together a working version.

My understanding is, it should go something like this:

```
tar -cf ~/Desktop/archive.tar "/path/somefile.txt" "/path2/some folder" "/path3/some other folder"
```

I have two drafts that look promising to me. I'm guessing, either could work.

From the OS X Finder the files get passed to the shell script either as arguments or to `stdin`.

**Attempt 1** (`/bin/bash`, pass input `as arguments`)

```
files=''
path=''

for f in "$@"
do
    path=`dirname "$f"`
    file=`basename "$f"`

    files=$(printf '%s -C "%s" "%s"' "$files" "$path" "$file")
done

tar -cf ~/Desktop/archive.tar "$files"
```

Here I tried to just concat the filenames and pass them to `tar` with the `-C` flag, which is supposed to change to the provided directory. Probably overcomplicated.

**Attempt 2** (`/bin/bash`, pass input `to stdin`)

```
tar -cf ~/Desktop/archive.tar -T -
```

This **is** working, but has a significant drawback: the full path gets saved to the archive (including my home dir name). Is there a way to make this only save the `basename` and discard the path (which is what I was going for with Attempt 1)?

I'm open to go with either solution, if somebody can help me to get it to work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly, so I can not provide an answer, though my intuition says that you're looking for something like this: `find .  -type f -print0 | tar cvf archive.tar --null -T -` Is it working for you ?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is supposed to be doing, but I think you're on to something. I do get a `.tar` archive with files in it, but not the ones I passed to `stdin`, but rather *all* files in my user dir. What am I missing? Or does it have to do with Automator calling the shell script and passing the files?

Comment: This line will recursively and safely ( dealing with file names with white-spaces ) `find` all files in PWD and create a `tar` archive from them, with the name archive.tar.

Comment: This is set up as a folder action?

Comment: No, it's currently a service (that accepts files or folders). The intended use is: select one or more files in the Finder, select the service from the context menu, have it create a .tar of the files. Actually, pretty much a direct port of the OS X 'compress' functionality found in the context menu of files/folders.

Comment: So you want to create a tar archive consists of only files, without any parenting directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedding quotes in the `files` variable doesn't do what you expect (see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)). You need to use an array instead:

```
files=()
...
    files+=(-C "$path" "$file")
...
tar -cf ~/Desktop/archive.tar "${files[@]}"
```

This'll execute something like:

```
tar -cf ~/Desktop/archive.tar -C "path1" "file1" -C "path2" "file2" ...
```

Comment: Thanks! This does **exactly** what I was asking. The files and folders get added to the archive, but without parent dirs or anything. Perfect. Also shows I know nothing about Bash.